# localStorage returns as undefined but works with console

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I wrote a JavaScript file which reads history from `localStorage` and logs it to the console. The value of the key `history` is a string array which looks somthing like this:

```json
[
  {
    "dateCreated": 1624953025609,
    "link": "localhost/97a4",
    "uri": "google.com"
  }
]
```

and as expected the key/value also shows up in the *Application* DevTools tab. I can also access the array in the console after `JSON.parse()`ing it like:

```js
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("history"))[0].dateCreated;
// 1624953025609
```

.
However, another JS file which looks like

```js
function checkLocalStorage() {
    if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {
        try {
            localStorage.setItem('feature_test', 'yes');
            if (localStorage.getItem('feature_test') === 'yes') {
                localStorage.removeItem('feature_test');
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

var isEnabledLocalStorage = checkLocalStorage();

if (!isEnabledLocalStorage) {
    $('<p></p>').append("Your browser doesn't support <b>localStorage</b> or it is disabled.<br><b>localStorage</b> is required to view your history.")
} else {
    var history = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("history"))[0];
    document.write(history.dateCreated);
}
```

writes `undefined` to the document. How do I get the value of a nested object from the `history` localStorage key?

Comment: history is a string, because you stringified it. Strings don't have property "dateCreated" so it's undefined, in console you didn't stringify it before accessing the dateCreated property, so that's why it's different. Just remove the JSON.stringify call from your else statement

Comment: I removed that but that still is undefined.

Comment: in your else statement you access the string from the local storage with the getItem call, then you parse it with JSON.parse, then you access the first element of the parsed array with [0] and finally you turn it back into string with JSON.stringify which is causing the issue, just remove it

Comment: please make a new comment instead of editing the last one since it makes the comment chain seem to not make any sense, also update your question with the changes you made, because i cannot tell what you changed, and you must have done something wrong if it still returns undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `undefined` because in your `else` statement, you call your variable `history`, but that already exists: [window.history](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_history.asp)

So instead of saving the parsed JSON, it fails to overwrite and when you retrieve the **`dateCreated` property, it doesn't exist on `window.history`**.

Just rename your variable to something like `saved_history`.

Comment: Can you explain the answer a little more?

Comment: There's already a variable called `history` and it can't be overwritten